# JavaScript In One Go Should Be Simple

Tags: php

Consider the code below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Visit_Date').on('change paste keyup', function () {
        var date = $(this).val();
        if(date == '2018-08-24') {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        }
    });

  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#Visit_Date').on('change paste keyup', function () {
         var date = $(this).val();
         if(date == '2018-08-25') {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        }
    });

   </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#Visit_Date').on('change paste keyup', function () {
        var date = $(this).val();
        if(date == '2018-08-26') {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
          }
      });
```

The above code works fine; it does exactly what is asked, which is: if the person has chosen the date 25th or the 26th August, then show the modal form "Sorry we are fully booked".

This is okay, but I want to be able to choose the dates I want, either individual or multiple (i.e. from 2018/08/1 to 2018/08/6).

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a range, you can do it like this:

```js
$('#Visit_Date').on('change paste keyup', function () {
        var date = $(this).val();
        if(date >= '2018-08-24' && date <= "2018-08-26") {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        }
    });
```

```css
#myModal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="Visit_Date">
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Sorry we are fully booked.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```